# java reflection on different argument number

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible to pass different number of arguments to a dynamic reflection method??

I have N classes, for instance

```
class A { method_A(T arg1, S arg2){}}
class B { method_B(T arg1){}}
class C //... and so on
```

I try to build a function able to invoke any method in any class

```
 main(){
   Object[] args = {"arg1", "arg2"};
   foo(new A(), "method_A", args);
 }
 foo(Object obj, String objectiveMethod, Object[] params){
   Method[] allMethods = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
   for(Method method: allMethods){
     //find the objective method, irrelevant to the question
     if(objectiveMethod.equals(method.getName())){
       method.invoke(obj, params); // Here throws IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
     }
   }
 }
```

I can easily retrieve the amount of arguments `Method.getParameterCount()`, but i can't figure out how to dynamically pass N number of arguments retrieved from `Object[] args;`.

I thought that `MethodAccessor.invoke(Object obj, Object[] args)` could handle this (because of Object[] args) but it doesn't work and throws

```
IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

Could you help me figure out any way to achieve that? Or it's impossible?

--edit--

```
 f(){
   A aObj = new A(); C cObj = new C();
   Object[] args = {"arg1", "arg2"};
   Object[] argsC = {"arg1", 2, new B()};
   aObj.method_A(args[0], args[1]); // works fine
   ...
   /* It doesn't matter which type of object they are, they still have known of it's type without casting*/
   method.invoke(aObj, args[0], args[1]); // works fine
   method.invoke(aObj, args); // doesn't work, wrong number of args.


   methodC.invoke(cObj, args...?);// 3 args dynamically
 }
```

Comment: not sure if I did understand the question: you need to convert the given array to a different sized array, that is, change its size, then maybe `Arrays.copyOf()` ?

Comment: What do you _want_ to happen?  You need to pick out the right number of arguments, but what do you want them to be?

Comment: So you claim `method.invoke(aObj, args)` doesn’t work when the method has two parameters and `args` is an array of length two? I suggest posting the real code, instead of pseudo code.